# SQL Server On Delete Event

Tags: sql-server, database, cascade

I've looked around a lot for the answer to this question, but I'm having trouble trying to implement cascade delete conditions between two particular tables in a database model I'm working. When I go to deploy, SQL Server keeps throwing an error saying that there might be cycles or multiple cascade paths.

Consider a table foo that has a primary key row of an auto incrementing int.

```
fooid|Column1|Column2...
------------------
1
2
```

Consider next a table bar that (among other things) has two columns which each contain foreign key references back to the id in foo.

```
barId|fooRef1|Stuff|fooRef2
---------------------------
```

I'm trying to implement a cascade delete operation between foo and bar so that if a row in foo gets deleted, any rows in bar that contain that id (in either column) get deleted too. There's a check constraint that the fooRef values cannot be the same in a given row. When I try to implement the cascade delete with "ON DELETE CASCADE" in both foreign key rows, I get that same deployment error about cycles and multiple cascade paths. I tried then to implement a trigger on the delete event for foo, where on delete of a row, it would delete all rows in other table with the foreign keys set to null. However in implementing this, when I then delete the check constraint and "ON DELETE SET NULL" for both rows in bar, sql still gives me that error.

I'm aware that the most easy fix for this would be change the model so that I only had one foreign key reference to the other table, but that's not really doable. What else could I do to fix this?

Comment: What is the exact wording of the deployment error you're getting?

Comment: Its about how the foreign key constraint should be changed because of the possibility of cycles or multiple cascade paths(I'll make that clearer in the question definition sorry)

Comment: Could it be the case that if I have an "On Delete SET" condition on the foreign keys in bar, and an onDelete trigger on foo to delete entries in bar, that the setting and deleting operations may not be happening how i think they are and that's what's causing the "cycles and cascade paths" error?

Comment: My guess is that SQL can't know if there's ever going to be the same fooid in both fooRef1 and fooRef2; if that's the case, it would have to delete the same record two times. TBH, having two fields pointing to the same field in the same table seems like an odd design choice, but I guess that's out of the scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by the trigger way to accomplish your task try to set values with an arbitrary value like 99999 and mark it as delete key in parent table , so the things can make sense
but the data will remain forever in child tables.
or

```
   1. set reference keys to null 
   2. Disable constraint
   3. Delete data in child tables having ref key as null
   4. Enable constraint
   5. Delete parent keys
```

Answer (score 0):

For reference, I never really figured out why this was going on, but I fixed it by only including the delete cascade on one of the 2 foreign keys